# Call a class constructor from HTML <select>

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In ECMAScript 6, say I have a couple of classes:

```
class A {
    constructor() {...}
    methodA() {...}
}
class B {
    constructor() {...}
    methodB() {...}
}
```

I'd like the user to be able to choose which of these classes to instantiate from a `<select>` menu. Here's a sketch of what I've tried (unsuccessfully):

```
<html>
<body onload="init()">
<select id="my_select"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

The `<select>` gets populated by `init()`:

```
function init() {
    var select = document.getElementById("my_select")
    var option = document.createElement("option")
    option.value = A.constructor
    option.text = A.name
    select.add(option)
    // ditto for B
}
```

And then at some later point I'd like to construct whatever was chosen:

```
var X = document.getElementById("my_select").value
var x = new X // doesn't work
```

What's the best way to do this? Is my approach completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your classes in an object which can then be referenced later via a value string.

```
class A {
    constructor() {}
    methodA() {}
}
class B {
    constructor() {}
    methodB() {}
}

let classMemory = {
    A, // Since you are using es6, you can do this
    B
};
```

Then, in the `init` function, you would do:

```
option.value = A.name; // Not using the constructor
option.text = A.name;
```

Finally, this works:

```
var x = new classMemory[document.getElementById("my_select").value];
```

Comment: Great answer! Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not this is the best approach for the task you are trying out I am not sure however if you wish to do this you can use the [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function that will allow you to execute dynamically generated JavaScript code.

```
eval('var x = new' + X);
```

It will obviously need tweaking to suit your needs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval